# Getting Postgres Database changes into Java application with Logical Replication

Tags: java, postgresql

Is there a way I can use PostgreSQL logical replication and consume the results with a Java application in real time? If yes any ideas, tutorials to start?

Comment: that's exactly what i need please mention it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual of the Postgres JDBC driver documents the integration with logical replication.

It also contains examples on how to use it:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/replication.html

Comment: The link is returning 404!